# Open jar file using JRE on Mac

Tags: java, macos, terminal, java-8

I have a jar file that is meant to be ran through the command line.

I am not planning to do any java development on the machines where the application will run and my thought process is that therefore I should only need the JRE and not the JDK. In addition, the JDK is like 4x as big as the JRE and I would like to not have to download it.

When installing the JRE on a Mac, it does not set the path for the java command and if I try to run it, osx prompts me to install the JDK.

I wonder if anyone could provide some insight as to how to use the java command in a mac without having the download the bigger sized JDK?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can either fully qualify the java executable path, or add the JRE_DIR/bin to your path.

Comment: Are you trying to run it through Terminal or by double-clicking the jar? Does the application use the console to print/read?

Comment: It has no UI, it is meant to be ran through the terminal or started by another process.

Comment: Did you try to run it using `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried running this in terminal?

```
java -jar MyJarName.jar
```

However, you can also try and make a runnable application of the jar file. Take a look at [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html)

EDIT:
You can also try running your starter class from the terminal. `cd` to the bin folder of your project, then `java packageName.className`.  For example, `java my.package.Starter`.

Comment: yes, it prompts to install the JDK if I try to use the java command. Will read your link now.

Comment: The command `java` without full path is only available on Macs if the JDK has been installed on them.

Comment: This is correct. I just had to find the path to the executable. You can find it if you go to System Preferences > Java > Java (tab) > View... > Path

For me it was:

/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java