# Can't open JAR files with JRE installed?

Tags: java, macos

I have several JAR files that I was able to run several days ago; however, now my Mac changed them to be opened with the Unarchiver program. I don't see any options for opening the file with the Java Runtime. I installed the latest update with no avail. I tried contacting Apple support. Nothing.

Any help would be appreciated it.

PS: I run OSX 10.9

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784846/open-jar-file-using-jre-on-mac?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the jar and use <kbd>⌘+I</kbd>
On the dialog you get there's a "Open with..." option:

[image]

open it and select the "Jar launcher" (on my mac, this application is located at `/System/Library/CoreServices/Jar\ Launcher.app`) for "open with" and click modify all, that should do it.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thank you :)